# Incorrect JSON format

Tags: json

I am trying to construct a JSON formats follows but running into below error, what is wrong with the below format and how to fix it?

```
{
    project_sha_list: [{
            project: project1
            sha: sha1
        },
        {
            project: project2
            sha: sha2
        }
    ]
    train: train1
}
```

ERROR:-

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   project_sha_list: [{
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: Put a comma between objects. Also strings need to be quoted, i.e. "project".

Comment: that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON should be:

```
    {
  "project_sha_list": [
    {
      "project": "project1",
      "sha": "sha1"
    },
    {
      "project": "project2",
      "sha": "sha2"
    }
  ],
  "train": "train1"
}
```

You can validate it [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=json+validator&t=canonical&atb=v65-5&ia=answer)

you keys and values both should be within `"`

Answer (score 2):

JSON keys and string values must be in quotes like below, but if the value is integer,double,long then it should not be enclosed in quotes, and if you have multiple properties each property should end with `,` except last one

```
{
"project_sha_list": [
    {
        "project": "project1",
        "sha": "sha1"
    },
    {
        "project": "project2",
        "sha": "sha2"
    }
],
"train": "train1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
{
    "project_sha_list": [
        {
           "project": project1,
            "sha": sha1
        },
        {
            "project": project2,
            "sha": sha2
        }
     ],
   "train": train1
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct jain format is:

```
  { 
      "project_sha_list": [
           { "project": "project1", "sha": "sha1" },
           { "project": "project2", "sha": "sha2" }
       ],
      "train": "train1" 
}
```